# Assigning values to a matrix, Right Hand Side is a Function of the Index

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I am trying to assign multiple values simultaneously to a matrix using MATLAB vectorization. In my code, I currently have something like:

```
y(1,:) = G(x(1:2,:))
y(2,:) = G(x(3:4,:))
and so on..
```

`G` is a function which involves relational operators with rows of the input argument as operands.

```
function g = G(x)
g = x(1,:) | x(2,:)
```

Is there a way to apply function G to the entire x-array without using a for-loop?

Thanks.

Comment: The answer depends on the definition of `func`. Please provide more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this type of function it is indeed possible. Define your function so that it works with all rows at the same time:

```
G = @(x) x(1:2:end,:) | x(2:2:end,:)
```

and then:

```
y = G(x);
```

---

Example: let

```
x =
     1     1     0     1     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     1     1     0     0     0
     1     0     1     0     1
     1     1     1     1     1
     1     0     0     1     1
```

Then `y = G(x)` gives

```
y =
     1     1     0     1     0
     1     1     1     0     1
     1     1     1     1     1
```